# Java: float, long local initialision

Tags: java, compilation, primitive, local-variables

I had been under the assumption, and indeed I believe that I have had experience, that initialising long or float local primitives in Java with raw numbers will generate compiler errors.

E.g.

```
float f = 10;
long l = 5;
```

And that the correct way to write the above would be

```
float f = 10f;
long l = 5l;
```

Yet I am finding right at this moment the compiler happily compiling without the f and l disclaimers. Am I missing something?

Comment: Auto widening. 10 is int, converted to float. Similarly for 5.

Comment: This question is now answered (SO delay in accepting)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That works fine because you are implicitly performing [a widening primitive conversion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2) from `int` to `float` and `long` respectively.

However this would not compile and you would need to add an `f` or a `L` to make it work:

```
float f = 1.0; //can't convert from double to float
long l = 12345678912; //12345678912 is not a valid int
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's take a look at the "fits into" relation in Java (just the types we're interested in). The graph looks like

```
                  double
                  /   \
               float  long
                  \   /
                 integer
```

So, in your case, integers 10 and 5 fit into `float`, as well as to `double`, so the implicit conversion does its work and the code compiles fine. However, `10L` is of type `long`, which doesn't fit into `int`. Same with `2.0`, it's `double`, which can't be assigned to `float` without explicit cast.

Answer (score 1):

If the integer literal you wrote is convertable to the target data type, it will be done **implicit**.